# Extracting specific information from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have data two sets of data as follows:
 "One.Two.Three.Four"
 "One.Two.Three.1.Four"

The first three parts are fixed and the remaining can extend to as many as possible.
I am trying to build an object where I want to split and combine whatever is present after three into an object.

```
var split = samplestr.split('.');
var finalarray = [];
if(split.length>4)
{
  finalarray[0] = split[0];
  finalarray[1] = split[1];
 finalarray[2] = split[2];
  finalarray[3] = split[3]+"."split[4];
}
```

I need to generalise this such that even if the string is of the form

```
"One.Two.Three.1.2.3.Four"

finalarray[3] = 1.2.3.Four;
```

Any hints on generalising this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
var split = samplestr.split('.');
var finalarray = [];
if(split.length > 4) {
    finalarray[0] = split.shift();
    finalarray[1] = split.shift();
    finalarray[2] = split.shift();
    finalarray[3] = split.join(".");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

simply replace

```
finalarray[3] = split[3]+"."split[4];
```

with

```
finalarray[3] = split.slice(3).join(".");
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string, slice the first part and append the `join`'ed second part:

```js
console.info=function(x){document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(x,0,3)+'</pre>')}
//--


var str = "One.Two.Three.Four.More.Stuff";
var s = str.split('.');
var result = s.slice(0, 3).concat(s.slice(3).join('.'));
console.info(result);
```